# Redis variable in Sidekiq and Puma, thread safe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, thread-safety, sidekiq

I'm currently building a dashboards app, and I'm not to sure that my solution is the right one.

Currently I have a Sidekiq Job that runs every 30 seconds. The job saves data to the DB and streams the new result to each dashboard.

The problem I had to solve is from this job to stream data ( with ActionCable ) only to the 'online' dashboards. ( If the dashboard was open in a browser tab )

The solution was to save in Redis from my DashboardChannel, like:

```
class DashboardChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
 def subscribed
   stream_from "dashboard:#{params['dashboard_id']}"

   tabs_number = $redis.get("dashboard_#{params['dashboard_id']}_online").to_i
   $redis.set("dashboard_#{params['dashboard_id']}_online", tabs_number+=1)
 end

 def unsubscribed
   tabs_number = $redis.get("dashboard_#{params['dashboard_id']}_online").to_i
   tabs_number-=1

   if tabs_number == 0
     $redis.del("dashboard_#{params['dashboard_id']}_online")
   else
     $redis.set("dashboard_#{params['dashboard_id']}_online", tabs_number)
   end
 end
end
```

I save the number of tabs open in a key "dashboard_#{DASHBOARD_ID}_online". Its kinda important to save the number of tabs because if you only save true / false (1/0), when the dashboard is opened in 2 tabs, and one is closed it will be marked as offline.

In my Sidekiq Job I have something like:

```
      if Dashboard.online?(widget.dashboard_id) # returns true / false
        ActionCable.server.broadcast "dashboard:#{widget.dashboard_id}", 
          { widget_id: widget.id, 
            dashboard_id: widget.dashboard_id, 
            value: data_value.value, 
            recorded_at: data_value.recorded_at.strftime("%I:%M%p"), 
            in_bounds: data_value.in_bounds
          }
     end
```

The Online method app/models/dashboard.rb

```
  def self.online?(dashboard_id)
    !$redis.get("dashboard_#{dashboard_id}_online").nil?
  end
```

In app/initializers/sidekiq.rb

```
url = ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] || "redis://localhost:6379/0"
uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] || "redis://localhost:6379/")


Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
  config.redis = { url: url, size: 4 }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
  config.redis = { url: url, size: 4 }
end

$redis = Redis.new(host: uri.host, port: uri.port, password: uri.password)
```

In app/initializers/redis.rb

```
uri = URI.parse(ENV["REDISTOGO_URL"] || "redis://localhost:6379/")
$redis = Redis.new(host: uri.host, port: uri.port, password: uri.password)

# Remove all 'online dashboard' keys
keys = $redis.keys("dashboard_")
$redis.del(*keys) unless keys.empty?
```

My question: Is it ok to use the '$redis' global variable declared in 'app/initializers/sidekiq.rb' in the Sidekiq Job? Is it thread save?

Currently I did not found a workflow issue wit this code approach, but I'm concern that '$redis' global variable, should not be 'near' a Sidekiq Job.

Feel free to add code recommendations. Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the thread safe has nothing with the global variable $redis. $redis just hold a connection to redis server. And the redis server is a single-thread model about process client request, so it will process request command as the command queue's order.

But notice that Sidekiq is multithreading. If your sidekip hold many thread and every thread will send command to redis server. There will be a thread safe problem.  please read the [transaction of redis](https://redis.io/topics/transactions) to learn more.

About your code, I do not understand very much. But in one point, if your DashboardChannel's subcribe and unsubcribe is running in multithreading or multiprocessing, you should notice that the bad thing will happen.

e.g. if the action  happens in the order below,

number1 = client-1 get key

number2 = client-2 get key

client-1 set key number1 + 1

client-2 set key number2 + 1

Then your key will hold an incorrect value opposed to the real number. If So, try use the redis watch.

Comment: Really good explanation! But I'm not quite sure how the example would fail (and keep incorrect values). So to be clear there is no problem for me to use the $redis connection as a global variable and allow Sidekiq Jobs accessing it. ( from the Redis docs I can see that Redis is single threaded. Thank you :)